# model.trainable = False - weights frozen and untrainable?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am using EfficientNet model (https://keras.io/api/applications/efficientnet/#efficientnetb0-function) with weights from ImageNet and I want to use a customized top, so I stated `top = False`. I am now wondering if the weights of the EfficientNet are frozen and they are not getting retrained (that is what I want) when I use the following code:

```
efnB0_model = efn.EfficientNetB0(include_top=False, weights="imagenet", input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
efnB0_model.trainable = False
```

Or do I have to use another code?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did works, but people generally do it layer by layer instead, because you might eventually decide to unfreeze certain layers:

```
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
```

`model.layers` returns a list, so you can also unfreeze just the last few layers:

```
for layer in model.layers[-10:]:
    layer.trainable = False
```

You can verify what *can* be trained with

```
model.trainable_variables
```

```
[]
```

In this case, nothing.

Comment: Thank you very much :-)